# ${GIT_BRANCH} not recognized by Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Job that uses the variable `${GIT_BRANCH}` and it works fine.

I tried using a Jenkins pipeline instead of the Job.

I have the following script:

```
node {

   checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branch: [[name: '*feature/myProject*']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], gitTool: 'jgit', submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[creadentialsId: 'XXXX', url: 'git@myrepo.com/myProject.git']]])

   echo "${GIT_BRANCH}"  
}
```

For this, I get:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: GIT_BRANCH for class: groovy.lang.Binding
at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java: 63)
```

If I change the final line to:

`echo "${env.GIT_BRANCH}"`

I get the same error.

I don't understand, why is the variable not recognised when I use a pipeline but it's recognised otherwise?

Comment: They currently are not present in pipeline jobs. See [JENKINS-35230](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35230).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known bug in the pipeline, I've seen it work, an update happens it stops working, I got tired of it and just started setting it myself.

```
def branch = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').trim()
```

Comment: This command sometimes returns HEAD instead of the branch name.

Comment: As @omeka commented, this returns HEAD on my tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a scm variable and append it to your checkout    such as :

```
scm: ... 
checkout scm: scm
```

And then you can access a lot of properties from the `scm` variable, including branch information.

Comment: Which property gives branch name?